# Optimize this query using a Join and Group By?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can I optimize this query using a Join and Group By?

```
 SELECT PM.Program_ID, 
                PM.[Program_Name], 
                ISNULL(
         (
             SELECT TOP 1 VF.ReadBy
             FROM VVF_ScriptFlow VF
             WHERE VF.ProgramId = PM.Program_ID
             ORDER BY VF.Id DESC
         ), 'NA') AS CurrentOwner
         FROM Program_Master PM
         WHERE PM.Department_ID = @DepartmentId;
     END;
```

Comment: Always use table name (or their aliases) when writing correlated subqueries. It's not obvious for the next developer who inherits the code.

Comment: If there are multiple values of _ReadBy_ in _VVF_ScriptFlow_ that corresponds to each _ProgramId_, then you cant use a `left join` and `group by` with what your current script is trying to do. You can make the code a bit clearer by using `APPLY`, which does the same as your subquery, but AFAIK, that's about it.

Comment: @KristianneNerona I think you are right.

Answer (score 1):

For this query:

```
SELECT pm.Program_ID, pm.[Program_Name],
       isnull((select top 1 s.ReadBy
               from VVF_ScriptFlow s
               where s.ProgramId = pm.Program_ID  -- hope I got the table alisses right
               order by Id desc
              ), 'NA') as CurrentOwner
FROM Program_Master pm
WHERE Department_ID = @DepartmentId;
```

You want two indexes:

- `Program_Master(Department_Id, Program_ID, [Program Name]`
- `VVF_ScriptFlow(ProgramId, id desc, ReadBy)`

I doubt you will get better performance with these indexes.

Note that this is one of the cases where you want to use `ISNULL()` rather than `COALESCE()`.  SQL Server is rather stupid about how it treats `COALESCE()` (well, I might say malicious in the interpretation of the standard); with `COALESCE()` it will evaluate the subquery twice when the value is not `NULL`.

Comment: Thanks for answer but i think your answer and my query is almost same with exception of table aliases. I am wondering if we somehow use join between 2 tables.

Comment: @Gordon, do you have a link for that thing with coalesce?

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis . . . https://www.itprotoday.com/sql-server/coalesce-vs-isnull, for example.  Note:  I still prefer `coalesce()`, unless the first argument is clearly expensive.

Answer (score 1):

Not much to go on here since we don't have table definitions, indexes, row counts or an execution plan. All of which are instrumental when dealing with performance problems.

My blind guess is to try an OUTER APPLY. It may or may not be anything different but I can't actually test anything. I would also urge you to always specify which table a column comes from. It is really hard to decipher when you don't know.

```
SELECT 
    pm.Program_ID, 
    pm.[Program_Name],
    ISNULL(x.ReadBy, 'NA') AS CurrentOwner
FROM Program_Master pm
outer apply
(
    SELECT TOP 1 sf.ReadBy 
    FROM VVF_ScriptFlow sf
    WHERE sf.ProgramId = pm.Program_ID 
    ORDER BY sf.Id DESC
) x
WHERE pm.Department_ID = @DepartmentId;
```